# Altium Designer 19 net name hidden on tracks

Tags: pcb, altium

In Altium Designer 10, the PCB file will show Net Names on Tracks and designator on footprint, like this picture:

[image: Altium Designer 10 shows net name and designator]

but in Altium Designer 19, the Net Name and designator are both hidden:

[image: Altium Designer 19 hides net name and designator]

Does someone know how to set Altium Designer 19 to show Net name and designator?

Answer (score 1):

In the PCB view, in 2D design view:

Press 'L' to bring up the View configuration dialog:

[image: AD19 view configuration dialog]

Select the 'view options' tab

Scroll to the bottom and you will see the view options. The ones in blue are visible. the ones greyed out are not.

Changes take effect immediately, so you can watch the view toggle on screen as you turn these options on and off.

Comment: thanks, but I have tried each view option, no one works on Net Name or designator